# How to remap topics after launching from the same launch file

Tags: ros2, realsense-camera, launch-file

I am trying to run two intel RealSense D455 cameras in sync to pull the pointcloud2 data. How can I remap the topics to prevent them both from streaming to the same topic?

Here is what I have:

```
# Include launch for serial number 213622300126
    included_launch = launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(['/home/robotix/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/launch/rs_launch.py']),
        launch_arguments={
            'align_depth': 'true',
            'pointcloud.enable': 'true',
            'initial_reset': 'true',
            'enable_sync': 'true',
            'device_type': 'd455',
            'serial_no': '213622300126',
        }.items(),
    )

    # Include launch for serial number 213622300332
    included_launch2 = launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(['/home/robotix/ros2_ws/src/realsense-ros/realsense2_camera/launch/rs_launch.py']),
        launch_arguments={
            'align_depth': 'true',
            'pointcloud.enable': 'true',
            'initial_reset': 'true',
            'enable_sync': 'true',
            'device_type': 'd455',
            'serial_no': '213622300332',
        }.items(),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The [launch file documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Launch-file-different-formats.html) provides this example:

```
    forward_turtlesim_commands_to_second_turtlesim_node = Node(
            package='turtlesim',
            executable='mimic',
            name='mimic',
            remappings=[
                ('/input/pose', '/turtlesim1/turtle1/pose'),
                ('/output/cmd_vel', '/turtlesim2/turtle1/cmd_vel'),
            ]
        )
```

Take a look at the `remappings` portion: you can change the name of a topic for a specific node by 'remapping' it. In this case, `/input/pose` is being renamed to `/turtlesim1/turtle1/pose`, and the `cmd_vel` topic is also being remapped.

But in your case, you're not using the `Node` approach, so instead you can use GroupAction and SetRemap (as described [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/101126/ros2-launch-using-includelaunchdescription-and-remapping-topics)).

You can group an action (or set of actions) with the GroupAction, and then within that GroupAction, you can call SetRemap to remap the topic. Per that link:

```
nav_include = GroupAction(
    actions=[

        SetRemap(src='/cmd_vel',dst='/cmd_vel_nav'),

        IncludeLaunchDescription(
             PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(nav_pkg_path + '/launch/bringup_launch.py'),
             launch_arguments = {
                   'use_sim_time' : use_sim,
                   'map' : map_file_name,
                   'autostart' : 'true',
                   'slam' : do_mapping,
                   'params_file' : [configured_params]

             }.items(),

        )
    ]
)
```